# Calling methods with parameters in Java

Tags: java, loops, methods

So I have to make a program in class and i'm having some trouble.
I have to call the examAverage method, which has parameters and i'm not sure how to. Also, in the user prompts method, I have to make a loop in main that call user prompts method and ask the user to input their exam score 3 times to get the average. I hope I explained it well. Im not very good at programming.

```
package project5;

import java.util.*;

public class Project5 {

    static final int NUM_EXAMS = 3;

    static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //declare variable       
        double Average;
        double examScore1 = 0;
        double examScore2 = 0;
        double examScore3 = 0;

        double Average = examAverage(examScore1, examScore2, examScore3) / NUM_EXAMS;
        printWelcome();
        userPrompts();
        display();

    }

    static void printWelcome() {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Exam Average Calculator");
    }

    public static void userPrompts() {
        System.out.println("Please enter your 1st exam score.");
        double examScore1;
        examScore1 = console.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Please enter your 2nd exam score.");
        double examScore2;
        examScore2 = console.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Please enter your 3rd exam score.");
        double examScore3;
        examScore3 = console.nextDouble();
    }

    public static void display() {
        double examAverage = 0;

    }

    public static double examAverage(double examScore1, double examScore2, double examScore3, double sum, double NUM_EXAMS) {
        double Average;

        sum = examScore1 + examScore2 + examScore3;

        Average = (double) sum / NUM_EXAMS;

        return Average;

    }

    public static void displayAverage(double Average) {
        Object[] examAverage = null;

        System.out.println("Your exam average is  %.2f%", examAverage);

    }

    public static double examAverage(double examScore1, double examScore2, double examScore3) {
        double Average;
        {
            return double Average
```

Comment: _I have to make a loop in main that call user prompts method and ask the user to input their exam score 3 times_ What have you tried?

Comment: There seem to be multiple questions in here. Try to separate these out into separate questions. What line of code are you having trouble with? Where are you trying to call the `examAverage` function and failing? Is it a problem with **calling** the function, or **implementing** it? Are you getting a compile error? If so, what is it? Or is it a runtime error?

Answer (score 1):

So your exam average function is all messed up, what you want is it to take number of exams and the individual values and return the average. 
So you make the function like this because you don't need to have sum as a parameter.

```
public static double examAverage(double examScore1, double examScore2, double examScore3, double NUM_EXAMS) {
    double Average;

    double sum = examScore1 + examScore2 + examScore3;

    Average = sum / NUM_EXAMS;

    return Average;

}
```

So when you call this function, you need to give it 4 values

so call it like this

```
double Average = examAverage(examScore1, examScore2, examScore3, 3);
```

That should solve your issue with the function. Let me know if I didn't explain it clearly enough or if you want me to elaborate.

You also have an issue on what order you call your code.
First, you want to welcome the user, then you want to ask them for their values, then you want to use those values to calculate the average and then you want to print that average so do this instead.

```
        //declare variable       
    double Average;
    double examScore1 = 0;
    double examScore2 = 0;
    double examScore3 = 0;


    //Welcomes user, then prompts for exam values, calculates average using those values, and finally displays the average
    printWelcome();
    userPrompts();
    double Average = examAverage(examScore1, examScore2, examScore3, 3);
    System.out.println("your average is" + Average)
```

Also, delete your Display() and DisplayAverage() functions, they are useless.

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to do your homework for you but you call a method with paramaters severals times in your code. For example inside your main:

examAverage(examScore1, examScore2, examScore3)

you call the examAverage method passing in 3 variables.  Your three variables are all set to 0, so that makes no sense. you probably should call your userPrompts before you call your examAverageMethod to initialize your examscores.

your program looks like it's almost done, think about the order of how you want to do it. good luck

Answer (score 0):

On way would be to call your variables static by defining at class level like:

```
private static double examScore1 = 0;
private static double examScore2 = 0;
private static double examScore3 = 0;
```

Other best way would be to wrap all these variables in a class (or better create a list/array) and pass that call in userPrompts method and populate it and then using same object you calculate average.

Regarding looping, here's how you could do it:

```
create a counter and initialize it with 0.
while count <= 3
do
     ask input from user
     calculate average
     display the average
done
```